# How to display an overlay layer (geoJSON) in specific scales with javascript/geoserver

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, geojson

I have a base layer of a map that is visible in 6 scales as shown below (myscales) and i have and additional geoJSON layer as an overlay but i want it to be visible only in scales 150000, 200000 and 250000. Any thoughts for doing this?

```
var myscales= [25000, 50000, 100000, 150000, 200000, 250000];


 //set style for geojson layer
    // grey color when deselected
        var gardenStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({ 
            'fillColor':'#737373',
        'strokeColor':'#737373',
        'strokeWidth':2,
        'fillOpacity':0.5
        });
        // red color when selected
        var selectedGardenStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
            'fillColor':'#ff3333',
        'strokeColor':'#ff3333',
        'strokeWidth':2,
        'fillOpacity':0.5
        });
        // Set up style map for gardens
        var gardenStyleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default': gardenStyle,'select': selectedGardenStyle});
    // Define the gardens GeoJSON layer
        var gardensLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("gardens", {
            projection: 'EPSG:2100',
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "gardens.geojson", 
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            }),
            styleMap: gardenStyleMap,
        visibility:false
        });

map.addLayer(gardensLayer);
```

Comment: which library are you using for the map? I believe this is strongly dependant on the **map** library that you are using.

Comment: @ZombieChowder I am using OpenLayers

Comment: You can set minResolution and/or maxResolution options on the layer